# FontAwesome, Bootstrap and screenreader accessibility

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility, font-awesome, screen-readers

I'm wondering about screen reader accessibility using Twitter Bootstrap framework and FontAwesome icon fonts.

I'm looking at 2 different icon situations:

1) The icon has helper text that a screen reader will pick up:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span> Edit</a>
```

2) And a standalone icon without any helper text:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button" title="Edit"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></a>
```

Ideally, in both situations, a screen reader will announce that the element is an "Edit" button.

Per FontAwesome's site:

> Font Awesome won't trip up screen readers, unlike other icon fonts.

I don't see any `speech` css tags related to FontAwesome or Bootstrap and not really clear to me how a screen reader will react to each of these situations.

I'm also aware of `aria-hidden` and Bootstrap's `.sr-only` and there has to be an ideal way to handle both situations.

Edit: added `title="Edit` to example 2.

What advantage does using `aria-label="Edit"` have over the standard `title="Edit"`?

Edit 2: I came across [this article](http://pauljadam.com/blog/javascript/image-text-inside-a-link-accessibility-issues-alt-title-attribute-expandedcollapsed-state-wai-aria-aria-expanded/) that explains pros and cons of different use implementations.

Comment: If you want to support screen readers, you have one or multiple screen readers you're testing with I suppose? Have you tried to see how they currently react?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding this, but surely, in the second example, you can simply use the title attribute in the a href tag? - title="Edit". Heck, you can go the whole hog with accessibility and actually add info on what the edit button relates to - title="Edit the content xyz". I guess it depends on your surrounding structure. If your edit button is within an article or a section, I guess the screenreader would be able to determine exactly *what* it is that will be edited. So, in fact, your question is a good one, but opens up other questions. Basically, describe what is being edited!

Comment: @MatthewTrow You're exactly right. I forgot title="Edit" in situation 2. If that's all I need for a screen reader to 'read' it, that's perfect! I've also read about aria-label="Edit", but not sure what the benefit is over the standard title attribute.

Comment: @Stijn This would be ideal. It just seems like a major pain to set up and learn to use screen readers. If there's an accepted accessibility standard that people use, I'd rather trust it and stick with that.

Comment: The `title` attribute is not reliably announced by assistive technology. Do not rely on it alone for essential functionality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you should probably use `<button>` instead of `<a href="#">`. Empty links can be confusing for screen readers, but a button is a button. In short, links take you places, buttons perform actions. (http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/; https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5493/what-are-the-differences-between-buttons-and-links).

I would go with a variation of your first code sample, and utilize Bootstraps `.sr-only` class. If we update your code with `button` and add in the class, we have:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span> <span class="sr-only">Edit</span></button>`

We now have a more semantically correct button element; sighted users see the edit pencil icon; and screen reader users will hear "Edit". Everyone wins.

(Note, the `button` code is straight from [Bootstraps CSS Buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) section.)

Comment: Yes. To me, this makes the most sense. Thank you.

Comment: Edit: Looking at my application, many of the "buttons" do contain an href="..." and they link to the content's edit page. So they are links that look like a button.

Comment: Glad it makes sense. And for button vs link, it certainly isn't cut and dried. Good luck!

Comment: .sr-only - this is exactly what I was looking for! I'll share this with my students!

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding I think it may be useful to also add in:

```
aria-hidden="true"
```

to the span class that holds the pencil icon. This will prevent the screen reader from trying to read this element.

```
<span class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```